# Using NOT operator to exclude compound words in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a problem with the NOT operator in Elasticsearch.
I start a query string query and look for these keywords:

```
plain~ AND NOT port~
```

I'm getting a list with documents which contains the word "plain" (that's ok) but also with the word "airport".
Is this the correct behavior and how can I exclude these compound words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is corect behaviour. Please have a look at the documentation for [fuzzy operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_fuzziness) and especially [fuzziness parameter values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness).

The point is that fuzzy operator "*uses the Damerau-Levenshtein distance to **find all terms with a maximum of two changes**, where a change is the insertion, deletion or substitution of a single character...*"

The word `airport` in you query is not excluded as it has more than two changes.

But this query would work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
        "fields" : ["description"],
        "query": "NOT rport~2"
    }
  }
}
```

It would exclude `airport` from the results. But you cannot increase the fuzziness factor to 3 as this is not supported (so this `"query": "NOT port~3"` won't work).

Your needs sound to me more like one of the cases of [Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html)